# My Wordpress site hacked with unwanted popups

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hacked

I have a woo-commerce shop on my wordpress but I've been attacked by some kind of hack.
As you can see in the image there are lots of popup link on top of my site . 
How can I clean this ?
I do not have any backup . 
[image]
thanks

Comment: Cleaning a hack is not that simple. You'll have to pay a professional if you don't know how to handle this. If nothing helps you'll have to rebuild your shop with a better password and up-to-date plugins.

Comment: Carefully follow https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a backup, cleaning up something like this can take a while. Each hack is different and can hide in multiple locations. If you have admin and FTP access these are the things I would change:

Change all the passwords for every account on the backend. I would also look into setting up a Cloudflare account as it can help add an extra layer of security.

**Plugins**

[Limited Login Attempts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-limit-login-attempts/): It'll prevent bruce force entry.

[Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/): Install it and have it run a scan on the site and directories. It should return any file that has been modified or is out of date.

I'd check through the **head.php** and **footer.php** files to ensure that they're aren't any scripts being dump in there. Sometimes you'll see a lot of random javascript or an iframe, delete those out.

Cleaning up a hack is time consuming and if you are unfamiliar with working with a text editor and FTP, you might want to hire someone.